# C++ arrays as parameters, EDIT: now includes variable scoping

Tags: c++, pointers, arrays, scope, subscript-operator

Alright, I'm guessing this is an easy question, so I'll take the knocks, but I'm not finding what I need on google or SO.  I'd like to create an array in one place, and populate it inside a different function.

I define a function:

```
void someFunction(double results[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i)
    {
       for (int n = 0; n<16; ++n) //note this iteration limit
       {
           results[n] += i * n;
       }
    }
}
```

That's an approximation to what my code is doing, but regardless, shouldn't be running into any overflow or out of bounds issues or anything.  I generate an array:

```
double result[16];
for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
{
    result[i] = -1;
}
```

then I want to pass it to `someFunction`

```
someFunction(result);
```

When I set breakpoints and step through the code, upon entering `someFunction`, `results` is set to the same address as `result`, and the value there is -1.000000 as expected.  However, when I start iterating through the loop, `results[n]` doesn't seem to resolve to `*(results+n)` or `*(results+n*sizeof(double))`, it just seems to resolve to `*(results)`.  What I end up with is that instead of populating my result array, I just get one value.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Oh fun, I have a typo: it wasn't `void someFunction(double results[])`.  It was:

```
void someFunction(double result[])...
```

So perhaps this is turning into a scoping question.  If my `double result[16]` array is defined in a main.cpp, and `someFunction` is defined in a Utils.h file that's included by the main.cpp, does the `result` variable in `someFunction` then wreak havoc on the `result` array in main?

**EDIT 2:**

@gf, in the process of trying to reproduce this problem with a fresh project, the original project "magically" started working.

I don't know how to explain it, as nothing changed, but I'm pretty sure of what I saw - my original description of the issue was pretty clear, so I don't think I was hallucinating.  I appreciate the time and answers...sorry for wasting your time.  I'll update again if it happens again, but for the meantime, I think I'm in the clear.  Thanks again.

Comment: If thats an *"approximation"*, can you post an example that actually exhibits the problem?

Comment: Just in case. Are you observing what's happening for i > 0?

Comment: @gf, good point.  by going back and actually looking at the code, I realized the difference between the code and what I posted.  Any thoughts w.r.t. the scoping issue?

Comment: @maciej h, I did try checking different i values.  produced the same results.  but...as I edited above, this turned into a different question now...

Comment: @awshepard, if i understand that right there shouldn't be any issue - can't you post a (preferably minimal) compilable sample that reproduces the issue somewhere?

Comment: Were you debugging a full-blown Debug build, or did you just enable debugging in an optimized Release build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a point about the variable scope part of the question - there is no issue of variable scope here. result/results in your someFunction definition is a *parameter* -> it will take on the value passed in. There is no relation between variables in a called function and it's caller -> the variables in the caller function are unknown to the called function unless passed in. Also, variable scoping issues do not occur between routines in C++ because there are no nested routines. The following pieces of code would demonstrate scoping issues:

```
int i = 0;  
{  
    int i = 0;  
    i = 5; //changes the second i, not the first. 
    //The first is aliased by the second i defined first.  
}  
i = 5; //now changes the first i; the inner block is gone and so is its local i
```

so if C++ did have nested routines, this would cause variable scoping

```
void main()  
{  
    double results[16];  
    double blah[16];  
    doSomething(blah);  
    void doSomething(double * results)  
    {  
         //blah doing something here uses our parameter results, 
         //which refers to blah, but not to the results in the higher scope. 
         //The results in the higher scope is hidden.  
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void someFunction(double results[])
```

should be exactly equivalent to

```
void someFunction(double *results)
```

Try using the alternative declaration and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hm...just tried that, and it still seems to persist.  I'm using VS2008, and one thing is that when I'm stepping through the loop, should hovering over `results[n]` force the debugger/variable viewer to resolve to `results[0]`, `results[1]`, etc? I thought it would do that, but it just shows `results[n] = ...`

Comment: @awshepard: You can verify wether the hovering menu gives the wrong result by adding `results[n]` or say `results[2]` to the watch window explicitly.

Comment: @awshepard: No, because the language specifies that the first case is treated like the second, the debugger would be unlikely to specially treat the second as an array. I don't use Visual Studio but there should be an option to display the pointer as an array.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that your code should simply work.

I just tried this in g++ and worked fine. I guess your problem is elsewhere? have you tried the snipped you posted?

```
#include <iostream>

void someFunction(double results[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i)
    {
       for (int n = 0; n<16; ++n) //note this iteration limit
       {
           results[n] += i * n;
       }
    }
}

int main() 
{
  double result[16];
  for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
  {
    result[i] = -1;
  }
  someFunction(result);
  for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
    std::cerr << result[i] << " ";
  std::cerr << std::endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you perhaps double defined your results array in a couple places and then accidently refered to one copy in one place and another copy elsewhere?  Perhaps the second is a pointer and not an array and that is why the debugger is confused?

Comment: I think this relates to my scoping question above?  Apparently this should work itself out (which is what I thought given c++ scoping rules), but yes, perhaps the debugger is confused?

Comment: Perhaps.  One never knows what the debugger is actually thinking.  Can you typecast your array in the watch window to specifically tell it what the var is?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure this problem doesn't occur, you should never use global variables like that. If you absolutely must have one, put it in a namespace for clarity.